# Is it possible to add one (or more) value per button click to the same row of a table then switch to the next row on the last button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, vue.js

I am trying to build an application that would mock clocking in and out of a job and store the information in a data table. Right now my process is one button to enter, one to start lunch, one to return from lunch, and one to leave. On each button click I would like for a time to be stored in the table, and a date in the case of the first button. I have tried implementing this in a few different ways and have never gotten an output in my data table. I think that one of the bigger challenges of this is how bad VueJS is at handling dates, and I'm wondering if that's part of what's messing me up. The other mystery to me is why nothing happens when I click on the buttons, I thought I would at least receive an error when clicking on the buttons, especially the last one, which should be opening a modal.

Here is the JS and HTML of my Index.vue tab where I house the buttons and the methods they should be calling.

```js
<script>
import * as actions from "../../../Config/ApiUrl";
import { TableHelpers } from "./TableHelpers";

export default {
    name: "Biometricos",
    mixins: [TableHelpers],
    data() {
        return {
            momentInstance: moment(),
            searchValue: '',
            deleteLoader: false,
            isAddEditModalActive: false,
            deleteConformationModalActive: false,
            selectedUrl: '',
            tableId: '',
            rowData: {},

            options: {
                name: 'biometricos-table',
                isAddEditModalActive: false,
                url: `${actions.BIOMETRICOS}/index`,
                showHeader: true,
                columns: [],
                datatableWrapper: false,
                showFilter: false,
                showSearch: false,
                showAction: false,
                actions: [],
                paginationType: "pagination",
                rowLimit: 10,
                orderBy: 'desc',
            },

        }
    },
    created() {
        this.options.columns = [...this.tableColumns];
    },
    methods: {
        getSearchValue() {
            this.$emit('input', this.searchValue);
        },
        ingreso() {
            alert('button pushed');
            const currentDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
            const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

            const ingresoEntry = {
                date: currentDate,
                time: currentTime
            };

            console.log('New clock-in entry:', ingresoEntry);

            if (!Array.isArray(this.options.data)) {
                this.options.data = [];
            }

            this.options.data.push(ingresoEntry);

            console.log('Updated data:', this.options.data);

            this.$emit('update-table', this.options.data);
        },

        almuerzo() {
            const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

            const almuerzoEntry = {
                time: currentTime
            };

            console.log('New clock-in entry:', almuerzoEntry);

            if (!Array.isArray(this.options.data)) {
                this.options.data = [];
            }

            this.options.data.push(almuerzoEntry);

            console.log('Updated data:', this.options.data);

            this.$emit('update-table', this.options.data);
        },
        regreso() {
            const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

            const regresoEntry = {
                time: currentTime
            };

            console.log('New clock-in entry:', regresoEntry);

            if (!Array.isArray(this.options.data)) {
                this.options.data = [];
            }

            this.options.data.push(regresoEntry);

            console.log('Updated data:', this.options.data);

            this.$emit('update-table', this.options.data);
        },
        openAddEditModal() {
            this.isAddEditModalActive = true;
        },
        closeAddEditModal() {
            $("#demo-add-edit-Modal").modal('hide');
            this.isAddEditModalActive = false;
            this.reSetData();
        },
        reSetData() {
            this.rowData = {};
            this.selectedUrl = '';
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left-side col-sm-4">
                <div class="tele-panel">
                    <h1 class="header-title display-4">TeleTrabajo</h1>
                    <div class="callout calendar-day d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <div class="grid-x">
                            <div class="shrink cell">
                                <h3 class="text-primary margin-left">{{ this.momentInstance.format('DD') }}
                                    <h3 class="text-primary text d-inline"></h3>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="auto cell">
                                <h3>{{ this.momentInstance.format('[de] MMMM [de] ') }}
                                    <h3 class="text-primary text d-inline"> {{ this.momentInstance.format('YYYY') }}
                                    </h3>
                                </h3>
                                <h3>{{ this.momentInstance.format('dddd ') }}
                                    <h3 class="text-primary text d-inline"> {{ this.momentInstance.format('HH:mm:ss') }}
                                    </h3>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <stop-watch v-show="isStarted || isFinished" ref="stopWatch" class="digits" hours="false" minutes
                        @start="setStartTime" @stop="setStopTime" @lap="setLapTime" /> -->
                    <img loading="lazy"
                        srcSet="https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=100 100w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=200 200w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=400 400w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=800 800w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=1200 1200w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=1600 1600w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&width=2000 2000w, https://cdn.builder.io/api/v1/image/assets/TEMP/7d7c128b9d97cdbc97e3f753e10d62e1d1922d448a7d54a60a1e245750a1eb93?apiKey=a927cef3079c4be4b43e485687f422e0&"
                        class="logo" />
                </div>
                <div class="divider-line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side col-sm-8">
                <div class="timbres mt-3 mb-3">
                    <app-button :label="$t('Ingreso')" class-name="btn-primary" :is-disabled="false"
                        @click.native="ingreso" />
                    <app-button :label="$t('Almuerzo')" class-name="btn-primary" :is-disabled="false"
                        @click.native="almuerzo" />
                    <app-button :label="$t('Regreso')" class-name="btn-primary" :is-disabled="false"
                        @click.native="regreso" />
                    <app-button :label="$t('Salido')" class-name="btn-primary" :is-disabled="false"
                        @click.native="openAddEditModal" />
                    <div class="search d-flex justify-content-end">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-with-search d-flex">
                            <span :key="'search'" class="form-control-feedback">
                                <app-icon name="search" />
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="searchValue" :placeholder="$t('search')"
                                @keydown.enter.prevent="getSearchValue" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <app-table :id="'biometricos-table'" :options="options" />
                <app-biometricos-modal v-if="isAddEditModalActive" :table-id="tableId" :selected-url="selectedUrl"
                    @close-modal="closeAddEditModal" />
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="buttons-section col-sm-6">
                <div class="horas-square ">horas</div>
            </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here is my Modal.vue tab that should be opening a modal to add the last parts of the table and clock out.

```js
<script>
import { FormMixin } from '../../../../core/mixins/form/FormMixin';
import { ModalMixin } from '../../../Mixins/ModalMixin';
import { DatePicker } from 'v-calendar/lib/v-calendar.umd';
import AppLibrary from '../../../Helpers/AppLibrary';

export default {
    name: "biometricosModal",
    mixins: [FormMixin, ModalMixin],
    props: {
        tableId: String,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            preloader: false,
            inputs: {},
            activeLists: [],
            modalId: 'biometricos-edit-Modal',
            modalTitle: this.$t('Te vaya bien!'),
        }

    },
    created() {
        if (this.selectedUrl) {
            this.modalTitle = this.$t('edit');
            this.preloader = true;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {
            this.save(this.inputs);
        },
        afterSuccess(response) {
            this.$toastr.s(response.data.message);
            this.$hub.$emit('reload-' + this.tableId);
        },

        afterSuccessFromGetEditData(response) {
            this.inputs = response.data;
            this.preloader = false;
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <modal :modal-id="modalId" :title="modalTitle" :preloader="preloader" @submit="submit" @close-modal="closeModal">
        <template slot="body">
            <app-overlay-loader v-if="preloader" />
            <form class="mb-0" :class="{ 'loading-opacity': preloader }" ref="form" 
                :data-url='selectedUrl 
                ? `masterdata/biometricos/${inputs.id
                }` : `masterdata/biometricos`'>
                <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                    <label class="col-md-12">
                        {{ $t('Salido') }}
                    </label>
                    <app-input class="col-sm-8"
                               type="time"
                               v-model="inputs.salido"
                               :placeholder="$t('select_valid_time')"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                    <label for="inputs_name" class="col-sm-3 mb-0">
                        {{ $t('Description') }}
                    </label>
                    <app-input id="inputs_name" class="col-sm-9" type="text" 
                        v-model="inputs.description"
                        :placeholder="$t('text_type_input')" :required="true" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </template>
    </modal>
</template>
```

And here is my controller which should be passing everything into the table.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Services\BiometricosService;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DateTime;

class BiometricosController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(
        BiometricosService $biometricosService
    )
    {
        $this->biometricosService = $biometricosService;
    }

    public function view()
    {
        return view('biometricos.index');
    }

    //Listar registros
    public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->biometricosService
        ->where('is_active', 1)
        ->paginate(request()->get('per_page', 10));
        return $data;
    }

    // Tomar 1 registro por $id
    public function show($id) 
    {
        return $this->biometricosService->where('id', $id)->first();
    }

    // guardar registros
    public function store()
    {
        $data = $this->biometricosService->save();
        return created_responses('data', ['message' =>  'Creacion de registro exitosa', 'data' => $data]);
    }

    //actualizar registros
    public function update($id)
    {
        $entity = $this->biometricosService->where('id', $id)->first();
        $data = $this->biometricosService->update($entity);
        return created_responses('data', ['message' =>  'Actualizacion de registro exitosa', 'data' => $data]);
    }

    // eliminar registros
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $entity = $this->biometricosService->where('id', $id)->first();
        $data = $this->biometricosService->delete($entity);
        return created_responses('data', ['message' =>  'Eliminacion de registro exitosa', 'data' => $data]);
    }

    
    
}
```

Further, I'm not sure if this code would do the trick for adding to the same row in the data table, so any advice on how to do that would be much appreciated!